# HttpSession java

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Eu estou a tentar implementar HttpSession no meu codigo mas esta a dar um erro no

> **request.getsession()** que diz 
>   **The method getSession() is undefined for the type HttpRequest**

Meu codigo

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;

import DAO.LoginDao;
import Impl.LoginimplDAO;
import classhiber.Utilizador;
@ManagedBean(name = "Login")
@SessionScoped
public class Login {
    @Autowired
    public String user;

    private  HttpRequest request;
    @Autowired
    public String pwd;
    @Autowired
    private LoginDao log;

    public Login()
    {
        log = new LoginimplDAO();
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public void red () throws IOException
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        List<Utilizador> result = log.findlogin(getUser(), getPwd());
        if(result.isEmpty())
        {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Erro",  "Falhado") );

        }
        else
        {
            //Contar objectos da lista
            System.out.println(result.size());
            HttpSession sessao = request.getSession();  
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Sucesso",  "Login") );

        }
    //  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(  
        //            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().  
        //      getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/registar.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar a causar esse erro ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente usar:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                                         .getExternalContext()
                                                         .getRequest();

HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                                           .getExternalContext()
                                                           .getResponse();
```